# write a post on user registration

Tags: posts

Looking for a way to automatically write a new post everytime a new user is registered. For example if when user B completes a registration form then a new post is automatically submitted (either by them or by admin) with "User B has joined [site-name]".

Is there a way to make a user account automatically post a post when the user registers?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ['user_register'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) WordPress action to add the post function. Use [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to add the post.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse_99270_new_user_post' );
/**
 * Add a new post when user registers.
 */
function wpse_99270_new_user_post( $user_id ) {

    // Get user data.
    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Add new post here.
    wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( sprintf( 'User %s has Joined %s', $user_data->user_login, get_bloginfo('name')  ) ),
        'post_content'  => 'Blah. Blah. Blah',
        'post_status'   => 'draft',
        'post_author'   => $user_id,
        'post_category' => array(1),
    ) );

}
```

Notes:

- It would probably be a good idea to post the new post as a `draft` and have it approved before being published.
- `wp_strip_all_tags()` is probably overkill.
- This posts in the category with an ID of 1.

Comment: Thank you this is excellent and I will implement it tonight. Could a similar system be used to write a comment on a post when a post is edited?

Comment: Sure. Use [wp_insert_comment()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment).

Comment: Thank you I thought that might work, I'll try and put together some code and post it as another question! Thanks again!